# onchange() in JavaScript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onchange

Good day,

I have a `drop down list` where have a onchange function call `updateView()`. `jsp` code is as follow:

```
<s:select name="accountDateRange" onchange="updateView();" id="function" >
```

However, there is not only this `drop down list` using this function. Some other function may call `updateView()` to proceed.

I have some code need to run when user do `onchange` on this `drop down list`, but I do not want this code to be run when other function call `updateView()`.

Following is part of code of `updateView()`:

```
function updateView() {

    // some other code here

        // here is the code that I only want to run during onchange
        $("#fromDate").val("");

    // some other code here

}
```

I have try to put in a `onclick` function in the dropdown, in this `onclick` function, I will set a variable to true.

So that I can using this variable to do checking before run the `$("#fromDate").val("");`, like:

```
if (onchangeOnly = true){
  $("#fromDate").val("");
}
```

However, I found that the `onchange` will run first compare with `onclick`.

Any way or idea to doing this? kindly advise.

EDIT :

```
function updateView() {

    // some other code here
    if ($("#function").val() == "TODAY") {
        // some other code here..
    }
    else if ($("#function").val() == "DATERANGE") {
        // here is the code that I only want to run during onchange
        $('[name="accountDateRange"]').on('change',function(){
                    alert('this is specific to this dropdown only');
                });
     } 
    // some other code here

}
```

I found that, even my `$("#function").val()` is not equal to "DATERANGE", it will also print out the `alert('this is specific to this dropdown only')`. Kindly point out what is my mistake.

Comment: why not add a parameter to your function `updateView` like this `updateView(para)`. Send `true` to this from where you want to happen this change for others don't send

Comment: Hi, this is a way to solve it. But I have a lot of function is using this `updateView`, if I add in a parameter, I need to do many modification. Thus, I prefer not to do this.

Comment: no you dont need just dont send from other end

Comment: As you're already using `jQuery`, why attach a handler like this `onchange="updateView();"`, if you could just do it like posted in the answer below (by @LIUFA)? That way you'll know exactly which element fired up the event.

Comment: it will be `undefined` for others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add more than one handler to same event, this means you can leave the existing function and write a new one and then add this function to dropdown so that other mechanisms triggering `updateView()` would be unaffected.

```
$('[name="accountDateRange"]').on('change',function(){
alert('this is specific to this dropdown only');
})
```

Comment: @LIUFA, have edit on my question. Kindly help again.

Comment: `$('[name="accountDateRange"]').on('change',function(){
alert('this is specific to this dropdown only');
})` goes into the page in separate `<script></script>`, and not into the function `updateView()`

Answer (score 1):

I'd do that in just jQuery without adding onchange to select element

#### js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#mySelect').bind('change', function(e){
    updateView(e.currentTarget.id)
  })
})

updateView = function (selectId) {
  if(selectId !== 'mySelect'){
    return;
  }
  alert('called from mySelect')
}
```

working plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/EmSowz6osgse2Ou8g6FC?p=preview

Comment: Your idea is better. +1

Answer (score 0):

onclick is not well for dropdown list just in the onchange function you need to use your function. And decide to use a parameter like this:

```
function updateView(bool) {
   if(bool){
    //do your stuff
   }
}
```

Another way is to add your new function in new onchange as mentioned by LIUFA but please make sure to use stopPropagation or return false to make it work.